# Can emacs paste image directly from the clipboard？

Tags: image, emacs

Today I just found out I can paste image into the emacs.
However when I close the file `C-x-k` to close the file,reopen again the image was gone.

Is emacs copy from the clipboard just copy the data? But I just `cat` the file with image , and nothing found about the image. There is no data,no filename like:file:filename.

How could this work?

```
emacs-mac-port 24.5
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: 1) The file format needs to support embedding images.  Emacs usually edits plain text files, and though the *in-memory* buffer can display embedded images, a plain text file on disk can't store images.  I won't say that it's impossible for Emacs to edit a file that supports such a thing, but I've never seen it.
2) Even if the file format supported embedded images, your terminal almost certainly won't display them (there are experimental terminals that can do this though).